# Как решить ошибку Illegal characters found in URL?

Tags: php, битрикс24, php-curl

Есть такой вот код, я на нем смотрю xml, но никак не могу сохранить его у себя. Помогите пожалуйста решить этот вопрос, даже незнаю куда копать

```
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");
/*
 * Настройки
 */
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/1c_exchange/core/options.php");
/*
 * Функции
 */
require($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/1c_exchange/core/functions.php");

$reader = new XMLReader();
$xmlfile = GetXML("users");
if (!$reader->xml($xmlfile)){
    $error_text = date("d.m.Y H:i:s")." - Импорт сотрудников: полученный ответ от веб-сервиса не удалось открыть на чтение, как xml файл";
    hlb_import_log($error_text);
    die($error_text);
}
$path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].log_users.'hlb_import_users.xml';
$pathd = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].log_users;
$fp = fopen($pathd. 'hlb_import_users.tmp', 'w+'); // не забываем убедится что в системе установлены права на запись файла
$ch = curl_init($xmlfile);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
if(curl_exec($ch)){
  // ok, файл загружен, заменяем
  rename($path.'hlb_import_users.tmp', $path.'hlb_import_users.xml');
}
else{
echo $path;
  echo strtr("Во время загрузки файла произошли ошибки :error\r\n", array(
    ':error' => curl_error($ch),
  ));
}
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Попробуйте прочитать: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47209890/15331960

Comment: @YaMus а какой именно url я должен менять? можно же получается через trim?